# No function matches, error is not obvious for anyelement

Tags: postgresql

When try to use the function below with `SELECT * FROM t WHERE checkrange(3,r)`, returns an error "No function matches"

```
CREATE FUNCTION checkRange(
     p_val anyelement, p_range anyarray
) RETURNS boolean AS $f$
     SELECT bool_or(p_val <@ r) FROM unnest(p_range) t(r);
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

---

Suppose

```
CREATE TABLE t (id serial, r int4range[]); 
INSERT INTO t (r) VALUES 
  ('{"[2,5]","[100,200]"}'::int4range[]),
  ('{"[6,9]","[201,300]"}'::int4range[]);
```

PS: I remember that we need to do some workwaround with PostgreSQL's `anyelement`, but not what... The error message is not obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's why:

from
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-type-system.html#extend-types-polymorphic

> Each position (either argument or return value) declared as anyelement
>   is allowed to have any specific actual data type, but in any given
>   call they must all be the same actual type. Each position declared as
>   anyarray can have any array data type, but similarly they must all be
>   the same type. And similarly, positions declared as anyrange must all
>   be the same range type. Furthermore, if there are positions declared
>   anyarray and others declared anyelement, the actual array type in the
>   anyarray positions must be an array whose elements are the same type
>   appearing in the anyelement positions.

So this will be ok:

```
select * from checkRange('[100,200]'::int4range, '{"[6,9]","[201,300]"}'::int4range[])
```

but that won't:

```
select * from checkRange(1, '{"[6,9]","[201,300]"}'::int4range[])
```

If you want your function to work with this anyarray just define first of it as integer to keep polymorphic arguments tied:

```
CREATE FUNCTION checkRange(
     p_val bigint, p_range anyarray
) RETURNS boolean AS $f$
     SELECT bool_or(p_val <@ r) FROM unnest(p_range) t(r);
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks... But the function returns a boolean, as I stated, is to use as `SELECT * FROM t WHERE checkrange(3,r)`. About your clues, is not a solution: even `checkrange(3::int4,r::int4range[])` not works.

Comment: Of course it won't because int4 is not the same type for anyarray `int4range[]`, the same types would be `int4, int4[]` or `int4range, int4range[]`

Comment: Please try with the example, and you will see that your answer is wrong.

Comment: It's ok - code works as I mentioned, which pg version are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using `psql (9.5.8)` ... See my solution, do you have better, or is the same?

Comment: Well it's better if you want to use polymorphic types and have one function, function overloading is obvious but try not to duplicate code - just call one function from another using type casting.

Comment: Ok, now you show both: the limitations (for an "ideal solution") and **the solution**.